# Android Studio виснет!

Tags: android-studio

Суть проблемы в том, что при нажатии на какую либо кнопку которая просит пк задуматься все виснет, появилось это буквально на днях, перезагружал пк, чистил и тд, не помогает, например, хочу выбрать цвет текста, если жмякнуть на кнопку для того чтобы появилась палитра, все мертво зависне, если же ввести цвет кодом, то все норм. Либо если я просто пиши какой либо элемент в .xml файле например TextView то все хорошо, но если я попробую, перенести его из списка объектов (Palette), опять же все виснет, когда завершаю процесс ибо ни как иначе, откидывает на шаг назад.

Мой пк: [image: ,]

Comment: Какая у вас версия студии? Может там баг какой-то. Попробуйте другую версию поставить. Вообще вам надо написать в баг-трекер гугла про это. Вряд ли вам тут смогут ответить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Регулярно проверяю версию студии, стоит самая новая.

Comment: Таки да, как советуют, попробуйте переустановить или поставить более старую версию или вообще бету 3 версии, если у вас "самая последняя"="последняя стабильная"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте просто переустановить Android Studio, в большинстве случаев помогает :)

Comment: отсутствует файл установки, скачать нет возможности, есть другие варианты ?

Comment: @VTeme, других вариантов нет. Только если в гугл написать и они что-то ответят)

Comment: Может быть проблема в драйвере видеокарты.

Comment: Вот его то я не обновлял со дня покупки, хотя карта новая, купил ее в начале августа NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

Comment: С таким железом проблем вообще не должно быть. Если есть возможность -- обновите драйвер.

Comment: Все обновил, не помогло, так же заметил , что в этот момент программа кушает проц почти полностью

Comment: Тогда баг в программе. Единственный вариант -- переустановить.

Comment: Косяяяяк прям ваше